# Error Saving ADF - Tango Explorer

Tags: google-project-tango

I have a problem with Tango Explorer App. I am trying to create an ADF file, but when I finish recording, I get a "Error Saving ADF."  I have updated to the latest OTA, and also the latest Tango Core. Does anyone have the same problem?

I have also tried doing a factory reset, but same results.  It records the area fine, it shows an Area Localized message, and when I touch the stop recording button, after showing an Optimizing popup, it shows the "Error Saving ADF."

Answer (score 2):

It's solved! What I had to do is uninstall the Tango Core App updates, then use the Explorer app, and then after accepting the Area Learning permissions and saving one ADF file successfully, I updated the Tango Core, and now it works perfectly.!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem here, it seems like the august update of the tango core changes something in the permission system (at least the dialogues are different), and that breaks the possibility to export ADFs to the sd card.