# Tango not saving meshes or adfs since updates

Tags: android, google-project-tango

I just got this tango last week for R&D at work, and I'm now having problems saving meshes in tango constructor and saving ADFs in tango explorer since the latest core and system update.

The tablet updated core itself earlier this afternoon (now running the 1.44:2016.09.19-wasat), and then core started crashing every time I tried to start a mesh in constructor or open explorer.

I found I couldn't roll back the core updates any more (it seems to have been removed), so I don't seem to be able to fix it with the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39026499/error-saving-adf-tango-explorer).

I then installed the system update (bringing me to build # kot49h.160920), hoping that it would fix the problem (as bringing core and system to the same level seems to have fixed things before).

Doing the update fixed the core crashing (so the dino app and the blocks app and whatnot work), but then on finishing the recording of the mesh in constructor, a little red android shows up on a bar near the top, along with some text that says "System unavailable. Restart the app or reboot the device", with an action required and red circle off to the right of the bar. At the bottom of the screen, it says "export failed".

Constructor doesn't actually crash every time though - just any time I try and save a mesh of more than about 250kB (as stated in the memory used in the debug for constructor). Between 100kB and 250kB, it gives me the regular "constructor stopped working" crash, and under 100kB the app actually works properly.

Explorer would open, but any time I tried to actually save the ADFs it crashed. Google play services also started crashing every 30 seconds.

So then I tried rebooting the tablet, reinstalling both constructor and explorer, rebooting again, and I was still getting the same problems with meshes, ADFs, and google play services.

I did the factory reset on the device (which didn't seem to drop the kernel down any, I'm still up at kot49h.160920, so I'm not sure if I did it 100% right), and that seems to have fixed the google play service problems and the explorer problems (it seems to be working now, with the occasional core crash) - but constructor still won't save unless it's a very tiny mesh.

I'm kind of hoping I can just get constructor to fix itself, as the unity demo I was hoping to do next week just needs the objs (and mtl/png) from it.

Also, I emailed the google tango help folks, but I'm on a bit of a time crunch

Thanks!

Oh - stats:
build #: kot49h.160920
core version: 1.44:2016.09.19-wasat-release-0-g41e380f9:190011587:stable
constructor version: 1.2.0 (service version 1.44)
explorer version: 1.42:2016.08.22-unukalhai-release-0-g13e1d179:11200:stable
Kernel version: 3.10.24-gd25b167, tango@atap#1, tue sep-20-09 09:41:34 bst 2016

Edit: If I update google play services, it starts crashing again. Whee. (That, at least, I can uninstall updates to and it fixes that).

Edit the 2nd: Screenshots:

Error when trying to export mesh:
[image: Error when trying to export mesh]

Tango core no longer allowing update uninstalls:
[image: Tango Core no longer allowing rollbacks]

Edit the 3rd: 
Went through troubleshooting with Tango Help team, they told me to roll back Tango Core (so if anybody can still do that, try that!), try uninstalling/reinstalling Tango Explorer, rebooting the device, try soft resetting it (settings/backup & reset/factory data reset/reset tablet), then try hard resetting it (turn on w/volume up+down and and doing wipe partition / factory data&reset / delete all user data). Did that, that didn't work, so they're now asking me to flash the kernel all the way back to Urquhart (yeah, from August 2015). I'm waiting on a) confirmation that they meant Urquhart (and not Unukalhai from last month), and b) a bit of a walkthrough on how to flash the tablet kernel as I've only flashed android stuff through rooting apps before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest Tango Explorer patch fixed it for explorer - didn't even have to reinstall. So, just update Tango Explorer (I did it through the google play store) and you should be golden.

Answer (score 1):

For my case,

Settings > Apps > Tango Core -> disable and clear data

then

app store > search tango core > enable

This makes my tablet save-able